# Listen to events from conversation apps like Slack and update Django database

Tags: django, events, twilio, slack, messaging

I want to build a Django app which listens to events from messaging apps and writes them in a database.

For eg, in Slack, on channel creation, I want to create a new entity in database and when a message is posted in that channel, I want to update that entity with the message.

I want the app to work similarly for other apps like Telegram, Discord etc.

How can I implement this using a common backend API for all the apps, i.e. a common API which listens to the events and updates the db ?
Or is there some third-party API available (for eg. Twilio maybe) which can fulfil my purpose ?

Comment: look into webhooks in each of the applications and have them call your application's api.

Comment: for slack use the Events API. https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api get that working with your app, then move on to the next system you want to 'listen' to.